# Endless pain and Belgian ale

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, language, cryptic-clues, geography

> 1. Endless pain with prosecutor is board game and peace garden place in anonymous organization (6)
> 2. South German to a Spaniard is Hebrew month in alehouse with well-rounded finish (6)
> 3. 100th Shakespearian king with blinded garçon is not obscure beverage (10)
> 4. Gold medalist and peeled field object give alcoholic beverage (9)
> 5. Floor covering and tin-pan wordsmith, secretly I'm a tiramisu (6)
> 6. Singer Scott and short princess reveal an agent next to me (5)
> 7. 11-kilometer paired number inside friendly expression (9)
> 8. Peakless Native American ruler returns a muzzle (4)
> 9. Feel Gaelic retracking large bird (5)
> 10. Belgian ale grows in the tropics (4)

What are we listing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe we are listing...

> Beaches

1. Endless pain with prosecutor is board game and peace garden place in anonymous organization

> Endless pain (agon(y)) with prosecutor (DA, district attorney, thanks @ferret!) = Agonda
> Board game (Go) and peace garden place (ND: North Dakota is where the International Peace Garden is located) in anonymous organization (AA) = Agonda
> **Agonda Beach** is a beach in Goa, India.

2. South German to a Spaniard is Hebrew month in alehouse with well-rounded finish

> South German to a Spaniard = Bávaro (Bavarian in Spanish)
> Hebrew month (Av) in an alehouse (Bar) with well-rounded finish (o) = Bávaro
> **Bávaro Beach** is a beach in Punta Cana, Dominican Republic.

3. 100th Shakespearian king with blinded garçon is not obscure beverage

> This one's great.
> 100th (C) Shakespearian king (Lear) with blinded garçon (Waiter without an eye (i) = water)) = Clearwater.
> Not obscured (clear) beverage (water) = Clearwater
> **Clearwater Beach** is a beach in Florida, USA.

4. Gold medalist and peeled field object give alcoholic beverage

> Gold medalist (Champ) and peeled field object ((m)agne(t)) = Champagne
> Alcoholic beverage = Champagne.
> **Champagne Beach** is a beach in Vanuatu.

5. Floor covering and tin-pan wordsmith, secretly I'm a tiramisu

> Floor covering (Mat) and tin-pan wordsmith (Ira (Gershwin)) = Matira
> Secretly I'*m a  tira*misu = Matira
> **Matira Beach** is a beach in Bora Bora, French Polinesia.

6. Singer Scott and short princess reveal an agent next to me

> Singer Scott (Bon) and short princess ((Lady) Di) = Bondi.
> An agent ((James) Bond) next to me (I) = Bondi.
> **Bondi Beach** is a beach in Australia.

7. 11-kilometer paired number inside friendly expression

> 11-kilometer = Seven Mile
> Paired number (even) inside friendly expression (Smile) = Seven Mile
> **Seven Mile Beach** is a beach in the Cayman Islands.

8. Peakless Native American ruler returns a muzzle

> Peakless Native American ruler = (Mocte)Zuma
> Returns *a muz*zle = Zuma
> **Zuma Beach** is a beach in California, USA.

9. Feel Gaelic retracking large bird

> Fe*el Gae*lic retracking = Eagle
> Large bird = Eagle
> **Eagle Beach** is a beach in Aruba.

10. Belgian ale grows in the tropics

> Belgian ale = Palm is a famous Belgian brewery.
> Grows in the tropics = Palm trees grow in the tropics
> **Palm Beach** is a... town in Florida (also apparently a beach in New Zealand).

Comment: It's [DA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/District_attorney) (district attorney) not NDA

Comment: Well done, all correct!